# Search javascript object to return the relevant catId

Tags: javascript, arrays, search, filter, javascript-objects

I have the following javascript array and I am trying to simply return the `catId` for an `id` - for instance if I search for the `id` of `10000356` I want to return the value of `4`. How should I do this?

```
categoryIds = [
    {
        "id": 10000282,
        "catId": 0
    },
    {
        "id": 10000340,
        "catId": 0
    },
    {
        "id": 10000341,
        "catId": 0
    },
    {
        "id": 10000334,
        "catId": 1
    },
    {
        "id": 10000333,
        "catId": 2
    },
    {
        "id": 10000336,
        "catId": 2
    },
    {
        "id": 10000337,
        "catId": 3
    },
    {
        "id": 10000356,
        "catId": 4
    }
]
```

```
categoryIds.filter(id => id == 10000356);
```

Expected outcome :

```
4 - the catId for `10000356` is the integer 4.
```

Comment: Use find : `categoryIds.find(obj => obj.id == 10000356).catId`

Comment: @JeremyThille NO ```categoryIds.find(obj => obj.id == 10000356)?.catId``` because find can return null if it doesn't find anything and here your code will break since you do not check it and you may try to return null.catId and that's an error

Comment: Ah, I thought the `?` operator was only available in Typescript, not in JS. Good to know. Yes I know, the result of `find` can be null, so of course one has to check for nullity and this kind of things.

Comment: Yep it is available in js, and this will prevent a bad copy past :P

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
const result = categoryIds.find((data) => data?.id === 10000356); // beware result can be null
// use ?. to avoid error if data is null
// rembere that you have an array of object not of id ;)
console.log("the catId for 10000356 is the integer " + result?.catId);
```

use find if you are sure that the id are unique and I think it's the case here.
find will return the data you want and return null if not found

Comment: if you use a version of js that doesn't support ?. can use some if like if (data) { return data.id === 10000356} else {return false}